# Regex to select term if it does not contain hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find the proper regular expression to select a term if it does NOT include hyphens. For example, I want to find the term `debt` but not `debt-to-income`.

I've got `\bdebt-to-income\b` which will select just `debt-to-income`, but I need the opposite. Help!

Comment: `\bdebt\b` still gets debt-to-income

Comment: @thg435 hyphen is a word boundary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following pattern: "debt" *not followed by* "-to-income"

```
\bdebt(?!-to-income)
```

This pattern can easily be expanded to restrict more, for example "`debt-of-the-usa`":

```
\bdebt(?!-to-income|-of-the-usa)
```

You should not *just* look for a hyphen, because `debt-free` (when `debt-free` means nothing) should also be matched, probably.

Answer (score 2):

Just use JavaScript:

```
var hyphens = 'debt-to-income';

if (hyphens.indexOf('-') == -1) {
  // No hyphens
}
```

Comment: I'm programmatically replacing words with links, debt needs to go one place, debt-to-income needs to go to another. When I get to replacing "debt" I need it to not affect debt-to-income, otherwise I'll end up with something along the lines of <a href="#">debt</a>-to-income and then I won't find debt-to-income. I can find the words with hyphens, I need to find the terms that specifically do NOT have hyphens:)

Comment: Well, @pstinnett the `if` case here will cover all non-hyphen variables.

Comment: Right. That code will only run if the string doesn't have `-`.

Answer (score 1):

```
debt\b([^\-]|$)
```

`debt` followed by a character other than a hyphen or end of string.

If you want to check left side as well: `(^|[^\-])\bdebt\b([^\-]|$)`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're looking for "term followed by not-a-letter but not hyphen":

```
term = "debt"
re = new RegExp("\\b" + term + "(?=[^\\w-])", "g")
text = "this is debt and debt, debtword and debt-to-income"
console.log(text.replace(re, "<$&>"))
```

result:

```
this is <debt> and <debt>, debtword and debt-to-income
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to find specific *words* in a stream of characters, where *words* are defined as a consecutive number of characters including hyphens, then I think \b needs to be abandoned as it in Javascript considers hyphens as word boundaries. Examples would be in-debt or debt-to-income which would be matched incorrectly according to the above assumption. By defining a *word* character instead as `[\w\-]` the following regex would match the correct *words*, but unfortunately require replacing a capture group as the first part matches the preceding character due to the lack of lookbehind support in Javascript.

```
(?:^|[^\w\-])(debt)(?=[^\w\-])
```